# Looking for corner burning plug-in

Tags: software, post-processing, plugin

At the newspaper I used to work for we had a plugin for PS that burned corners stupendously. Simple, easy to use, customizable, actionable plugin. BUT WHAT IS THE NAME OF THE THING?!? Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found it!!!! [Photokit](http://www.pixelgenius.com/downloads.html) by Pixel Genius. This pluging is awesome. Free for two months, I totally suggest checking this thing out. It does way more then just burn corners down (which looks way better then vignetting options I've seen) and everything is actionable.

Happy Hunting.

Answer (score 3):

You mean a plugin that creates [vignetting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vignetting)? If you [Google for it](http://www.google.com/search?q=photoshop%20vignetting#sclient=psy&hl=en&safe=off&source=hp&q=photoshop+vignetting+plugin&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=8a5b3ffa4becd4c9), I see more than a few, including [Xero Soft Vignette](http://www.xero-graphics.co.uk/set4/softvignette.htm), [MV's Vignette Corrector](http://photoshop.pluginsworld.com/plugins/adobe/1772/mv-s-plugins/vignette-corrector.html). The easiest way, in newer version of Photoshop, is just to use the Lens Correction filter, by selecting Filters > Distort > Lens Correction and [playing with the vignette slider](http://focusfaction.com/forums/showthread.php/1038-Easy-Vignette-in-Photoshop). For non-destructive editing, try to [apply the effect on a new layer](http://blog.epicedits.com/2007/09/18/quick-tip-using-photoshop-to-add-vignette/).

Comment: There is also a slider in Lightroom if that is your program of choice. Under the develop tab, scroll down on the list of adjustments.

Comment: Yes, definitely, I use LR extensively. He was mentioning PS though.